# Reading and Writing array of structs to a binary file c99

Tags: c, struct, file-io, c99

I Have a basic version of a HashMap implemented in C. However, i am trying to save and load it to/from a binary file. I am losing the data held within the array during this process however. I am pretty sure it is a error within my sizeof(hashMap) logic.

the hashMap structs:

```
typedef struct bucket{
int Hash;
int Key;
}BUCKET;

typedef struct node{
struct bucket data;
struct node * next;
}NODE;

typedef struct base{
struct node * head;
int length;
}BASE;
```

The decleration of the array

```
BASE * hashMap[hashMapWidth]
```

The code for saving:

```
 printf("Saving to File\n");
 FILE *fr = fopen("LinkedListArray.bin", "wb");
 fwrite(hashMap, 1, sizeof(hashMap), fr);
 fclose(fr);
```

The code for loading:

```
FILE *fw = fopen("LinkedListArray.bin", "rb");
long pos = ftell(fw);
fseek(fw, 0, SEEK_END);
long length = ftell(fw);
fseek(fw, pos, SEEK_SET);
fread(hashMap, (size_t) length, 1, fw);
```

Comment: Even if you output the correct number of bytes to your file (`fwrite(hashMap, 1, sizeof(hashMap), fr);` → `fwrite(hashMap, 1, sizeof(BASE), fr);`), your binary file would still only contain a single `BASE` struct, containing one pointer (`struct node *head`) and one integer (`int length`). None of the data pointed to by `head` is going into the file at all.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that is what i though was happening. Any idea how i could get around this? Or would i have to go through the linked list one by one saving all the data to file

Comment: Yes, you'll just have to work through the list. Bear in mind that you can't load pointers from disk and expect them to point to anything valid, so you'll also need to think about how the links in your list can be stored reliably.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage yea thanks for the help